# C++ the default constructor of cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++

I made class in visual studio 2022 (cpp) and when i try to create object of this class it says - C++ the default constructor of cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function, how can i fix this error?

the class:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "DeviceList.h"

class User
{
private:
    unsigned int id;
    std::string username;
    unsigned int age;
    DevicesList& devices;

public:
    void init(unsigned int id, std::string username, unsigned int age);
    void clear();
    unsigned int getID() const;
    std::string getUserName() const;
    unsigned int getAge() const;
    DevicesList& getDevices() const;
    void addDevice(Device newDevice);
    bool checkIfDevicesAreOn() const;
};
```

the error:

```
User user1; //C++ the default constructor of cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
user1.init(123456789, "blinkybill", 17);
User user2;//C++ the default constructor of cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
user2.init(987654321, "HatichEshMiGilShesh", 15);
```

Comment: You need one, which initializes your reference `devices` member variable. It's unclear why you need a reference there at all.

Comment: I have doubts that `devices` should be a reference in the first place. I suspect it should just be a regular `DevicesList` member

Comment: References must be initialised, the compiler does not know how to do that, so it cannot generate a default constructor. Removing the reference from your class seems like the obvious step.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add constructor to User class for initializing devices member reference.

```
public:
    User(DevicesList& dvs) : devices(dvs){}
```

after that, create user1 with DeviceList instance

```
    DevicesList devices;
    User user1(devices);
```

Comment: I don't believe that the OP actually needs a reference class member variable for that `DevicesList`.